# Not able to use bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp

Tags: libbitcoin

the libbitcoin library seems to have been installed just fine. 
but the following code can't seem to include bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp

```
#include<bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace bc;
int main() {
    block_type blk = genesis_block();
    std::cout<<encode_hex(hash_block_header(blk.header))<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libbitcoin)
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:5: error: ‘block_type’ was not declared in this scope
     block_type blk = genesis_block();
     ^~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:5:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘clock_t’
     block_type blk = genesis_block();
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     clock_t
test.cpp:6:45: error: ‘blk’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout<<encode_hex(hash_block_header(blk.header))<<std::endl;
                                             ^~~
test.cpp:6:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘brk’
     std::cout<<encode_hex(hash_block_header(blk.header))<<std::endl;
                                             ^~~
                                             brk
test.cpp:6:27: error: ‘hash_block_header’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout<<encode_hex(hash_block_header(blk.header))<<std::endl;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:6:16: error: ‘encode_hex’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout<<encode_hex(hash_block_header(blk.header))<<std::endl;
                ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run this code:

```
#include <bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp>

int main() 
{
  bc::ec_secret decoded;
  bc::decode_base16(decoded, "038109007313a5807b2eccc082c8c3fbb988a973cacf1a7df9ce725c31b");
}
```

Follow this https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin#debianubuntu

After compile it in a /home/x/dir run this:

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -I/home/dev/bitcoin-lib/include /home/dev/bitcoin-lib/lib/libbitcoin.a /home/dev/bitcoin-lib/lib/libboost_system.a /home/dev/bitcoin-lib/lib/libbitcoin.a /home/dev/bitcoin-lib/lib/libboost_program_options.a /home/dev/bitcoin-lib/lib/libboost_regex.a
```

- we need to tell g++ where are the headers for our #include statement
- We need to tell g++ what are the libraries: libbitcoin.a, etc

Comment: Don't forget `-lgmp` when it happens

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the -std=c++11 flag.

I had the same problem and the following worked for me:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libbitcoin)
```

Comment: it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

The book code examples has an accompanying actively maintained github repo [here](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook). However, extra care is needed for the `libbitcoin` library dependency as it has new breaking changes. For example, `#include <bitcoin/bitcoin.cpp>` has been rename to `#include <bitcoin/system.hpp>`. And no more `bc::ec_point`. It is possible to install an older compatible version of `libbitcoin` library, but I prefer to use the latest version and made some adjustment in `addr.cpp` example code.

I manually build and installed the `libbitcoin` library to a custom location [as suggested](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system):

```
mkdir -p /opt/my/libbitcoin/
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/version3/install.sh
$ chmod +x install.sh
$ ./install.sh --prefix=/opt/my/libbitcoin/ --build-boost --disable-shared
```

The way I now build `addr.cpp` is thus:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/my/libbitcoin/lib/pkgconfig/
g++ -o addr addr.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libbitcoin-system) -lgmp
```

And then, running the executable:

```
$ ./addr
Public key: 0202a406624211f2abbdc68da3df929f938c3399dd79fac1b51b0e4ad1d26a47aa
Address: 1PRTTaJesdNovgne6Ehcdu1fpEdX7913CK
```